# Why do English translations interpret the Ivri imperative "SOS" (שׂוֹשׂ) / "Rejoice!" as the English adverb "greatly" in Isaiah 61:10?

Tags: hebrew, translation-philosophy, isaiah

In the Ivri (עִבְרִי) / Hebrew (ἑβραιου) text of [Isaiah 61:10] we read **Rejoice** twice as an **imperative** then in **1ps future** tense :

"SOS" (**Rejoice!, שׂוֹשׂ**),
"ASIYS" (**I-will Rejoice, אָשִׂישׂ**).

- Note the different tenses for "Rejoice" : https://www.pealim.com/dict/2191-lasus/

**Isaiah 61:10 [MT]**

> "Sos Asiys BaYeHoVaH" (שׂוֹשׂ אָשִׂישׂ בַּֽיהוָ֗ה)

Question:
**Why do English translations interpret the Ivri imperative "SOS" (שׂוֹשׂ) / "Rejoice!" as the English adverb "greatly" in Isaiah 61:10?**

> Isaiah 61:10 [KJV] : " I will **greatly** rejoice in the Lord "
>
> Isaiah 61:10 [NASB] : " I will rejoice **greatly** in the Lord "
>
> Isaiah 61:10 [ESV] : " I will **greatly** rejoice in the Lord "

English translations change "Rejoice!" into an adverb "greatly". Yet the Ivri (עִבְרִי) word for "greatly" = "Gedool" (גְדֻלָּ), "great" = "Gadol" (גָּ֘ד֥וֹל). **The verb "Asiys" (אָשִׂישׂ) does not contain the "gedul" (greatly) adverb.**

**Is there any reason why English translations interpret "SOS" (שׂוֹשׂ) as "greatly"?**

Answer (score 1):

In Hebrew, a word is repeated for emphasis. It is a common technique. In this case, there is a repetition of a word with a change in the form of
the word.

The first example is in
Genesis 2:17,
New International Version:

> but you must not eat from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, for when you eat from it you will **certainly die**."

you will surely
מ֥וֹת (mō·wṯ)
Verb - Qal - Infinitive absolute
Strong's Hebrew **4191**: To die, to kill

die
תָּמֽוּת׃ (tā·mūṯ)
Verb - Qal - Imperfect - second person masculine singular
Strong's Hebrew **4191**: To die, to kill

Other examples follows:

> Deuteronomy 10:17 (NASB) “For the LORD [Yahweh] your God is the **God of gods** and the **Lord of lords**, the great, the mighty, and the awesome God who does not show partiality nor take a bribe.

> Song of Solomon 1:1 This is Solomon’s **Song of Songs**.

> Ecclesiastes 1:2 **Vanity of vanities**, says the Preacher, vanity of vanities! All is vanity.

> 1 Samuel 3:10
> The LORD came and stood there, calling as at the other times, "**Samuel! Samuel!**" Then Samuel said, "Speak, for your servant is listening."

> Ezekiel 26:7  For thus says the Lord GOD, “Behold, I will bring upon Tyre from the north Nebuchadnezzar king of Babylon, **king of kings**, with horses, chariots, cavalry and a great army.

> John 6:4
> **Truly, truly**, I say to you, he who believes has eternal life.

And many more ...